# Strange problem with two different objects having reference

Tags: c#, reference

When a ClaimDetail is added to tmpClaim, this ClaimDetail is also added to claim. Can someone explain me why this occurs?

```
List<Claim> claims; // list data
foreach ( Claim claim in claims) {
  Claim tmpClaim = datacontext.Claims.FirstOrDefault ( c => c.Id == claim.Id );

  ClaimDetail claimDetail = new ClaimDetail ( );
  claimDetail.ClaimDetailType = "Type";

  // add claim
  datacontext.Claims.InsertOnSubmit ( tmpClaim );
  datacontext.SubmitChanges ( );
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have two pieces of paper that both say "123 Sesame Street, New York City" on them.  I go to the house mentioned on the first piece of paper. It has a blue door. I paint the door of that house red.  Now I go to the house mentioned on the second piece of paper. Does that house have a blue door? Why or why not?

Comment: @EricLippert Arrgghh...found the problem, feeling stupid because I had checked the code many times. Seems the list 'claims' had some objects (from the datacontext) which has the same address. Was assuming that none of the items in the list had a reference to an object in de datacontext. Thank you for the response and explanation, it helped finding the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmpClaim` isn't a *new* object. It's still a reference back to an element within `claims`.

What this essentially means is that whatever you do to `tmpClaim` is also happening with `claims`. They are the same thing.

If you don't want changes to `tmpClaim` to affect `claims`, you'll need to create a `new Claim` (as well as any copying/cloning that is necessary) and do all of your work on that new object.

Comment: See my comment to @EricLippert. Thank you for the response and explanation, it helped finding the problem.